# xp:checkBox in edit mode does not match checked value from bean

Tags: java, checkbox, xpages

on an xpage I have checkbox control with data-binding to a bean e.g.:

```
<xp:checkBox text="Agree" value="#{proposalBean.proposal.mailNotify}" checkedValue="YES"/>
```

In the back-end I load the value from a Notes doc. When I load the xpage I get the correct value, but when I edit the object the value turns to false. It seems that it cannot match the value from the bean ("YES") with the checkedValue.

Is there a bug and a workaround r should I switch to a checkboxgroup control?

Comment: How does your backend code for the getter and setter look like?

Comment: if (doc.hasItem("ass_MailNotify")){
    if (doc.getItemValueString("ass_MailNotify").equals("YES")){
     proposal.setMailNotify("true");
    }
    else{     
     proposal.setMailNotify("false");
    }
   }

Comment: values are now stored as YES (text) or "" (emptry text field)

Comment: I surrounded a comment block around the checkbox control and then the value in the bean is not updated when switching from read to edit mode. so the control causes it I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I had to compute the readonly AND disabled property. I had only the disabled property computed.... :-?

```
readonly="#{javascript:!proposalBean.editable || proposalBean.locked}"
disabled="#{javascript:!proposalBean.editable || proposalBean.locked}"
```